# Statistical testing for unique combinations from a data frame

Tags: r, testing, dataframe

For the example data frame below I want to perform statistical tests (e.g. t-test) for all unique DRUG - ADR combinations. For this I need the following:

1) a vector of X for each unique DRUG - ADR combination

2) If my DRUG - ADR of interest is D1 - A1, I want to test the vector of X (here 34) with the vectors:

- D1 - all A's that are not A1 (in the example D1-A2, x = 37)
- A1 - all D's that are not D1 (in the example D4-A1, x = 65)

This procedure should loop through all records in the data frame and should disregard the ID variable since one ID can have several DRUG - ADR combinations. Obviously, my dataset is much larger and the resulting vectors from X will contain more than 1 value

```
dat <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,7),
                  DRUG=c("D1","D2","D2","D3","D3","D3","D5","D1","D4","D2"),
                  ADR=c("A1","A2","A3","A6","A7","A8","A4","A2","A1","A2"),
                  X=c(34,76,34,45,2,41,56,37,65,12))


   ID DRUG ADR  X
1   1   D1  A1 34
2   2   D2  A2 76
3   3   D2  A3 34
4   4   D3  A6 45
5   4   D3  A7  2
6   4   D3  A8 41
7   5   D5  A4 56
8   6   D1  A2 37
9   6   D4  A1 65
10  7   D2  A2 12
```

Looking forward to your suggestions!

ADITIONAL INFORMATION:
I cannot explain this using boxplot() so I will try it verbally. In this example I want to perform 2 tests for X for each unique combination of DRUG - ADR. So for D1-A1 I want to test versus D1-A<>1 and versus D<>1 - A1. For test number 1,  I need two vectors: one containing the values of X for D1-A1 (here 34) and one containing the values of X for D1 - A<>1 (so in this case D1-A2 (value=37) , but in my much larger dataset this would be a much larger vector containing values for e.g. D1 - A23, D1-A573 etc). For test number 2, I need vectors of X for D1-A1 (which I already have from test 1) and for D<>1-A1 (here D4-A1, value=65). Then the same procedure should be repeated for record 2 (D2-A2), record 3 (D2-A3) and so on. So for each record in the dataframe I need 2 sets of 2 vectors from X.

Next would be record 2. For this record the vector for D2-A2 would be (76,12), whereas the vector for D<>2-A2 would be (37; from record 8) and the vector for D2-A<>2 would be (34; from record 3). I hope this explains it

Additional comment: The syntax below decsribes the 2 tests for D1-A1. However, I would like a generalised function that loops through all unique Dx-Ax combinations and performs the same procedures (so in this case 9 times 2 tests since record 2 and 10 apply to the same combination).

```
x <- ifelse (dat$DRUG == "D1" & dat$ADR == "A1",dat$X, NA)
x <- x[!is.na(x)]

y <- ifelse (dat$DRUG != "D1" & dat$ADR == "A1",dat$X, NA)
y <- y[!is.na(y)]

z <- ifelse (dat$DRUG == "D1" & dat$ADR != "A1",dat$X, NA)
z <- z[!is.na(z)]

t.test(x,y)
t.test(x,z)
```

Comment: take a look at `pairwise.t.test`.

Comment: Then take a look at how `pairwise.t.test` is implemented and change the corresponding lines.

Comment: Can you include a plot in your question to show which groups you actually want to compare, e.g. using the `boxplot()` function. For me it is not clear so far.

Comment: See added information in question

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. `ifelse` is perfect here for grouping

```
group1 <- ifelse(dat$DRUG == "D1", ifelse(dat$ADR  == "A1", 1, 2), NA)
group2 <- ifelse(dat$ADR == "A1", ifelse(dat$DRUG  == "D1", 1, 2), NA)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
boxplot(dat$X ~ group1)
boxplot(dat$X ~ group2)
```

[image]

```
# for the test you can try following:
t.test(dat$X ~ group1)
t.test(dat$X ~ group2)
```

For the loop you can try this. Will be interrupted if there are too less group observations and will give you a list of all results. Otherwise you could use 
`t.test()p.value` to report only the pvalues.

```
res <- list()
n <- 2 # change here the number of tests
for (x in 1:n){
  D <- paste0("D", x)
  A <- paste0("A", x)
  group1 <- factor(ifelse(dat$DRUG == D, ifelse(dat$ADR  == A, paste0(D,A), paste0(D,"Ax")), NA))
  group2 <- factor(ifelse(dat$ADR == A, ifelse(dat$DRUG  == D, paste0(D,A),  paste0("Dx",A)), NA))
  g1 <- paste0(levels(group1), collapse = "_vs_")
  g2 <- paste0(levels(group2), collapse = "_vs_")
  if(nlevels(group1) == 2){
    res1 <- t.test(dat$X ~ group1)$p.value
  }else{
    res1 <- NA
  }
  if(nlevels(group2) == 2){
    res2 <- t.test(dat$X ~ group2)$p.value
  }else{
    res2 <- NA
  }
  res[[x]] <- cbind.data.frame(g1, res1, g2, res2)
}
do.call("rbind", res)
```

Comment: I have very little experience with functions, but if I'm correct I have to manually assign the groups using the ifelse statement. This would be nearly impossible since I have approximately 1500 drugs and 3000 ADRs. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: To make things more complicated: I need the p-values from the test in a table together with columns for DRUG and ADR. So a table with 4 columns: DRUG, ADR, pvalue1, pvalue2.

Comment: Almost there I think. Only now I get the message "Error in t.test.formula(dat$TTO ~ group1) : grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels". I suppose this has to do with NAs. If group1 / group2 were separate objects I could remove the NAs but I'm not sure how to do that in a function.

Comment: Any idea on how to make sure there are 2 levels?

Comment: If I run your suggestion I get a large factor for group1 and group2 (which seems OK), but for g1 and g2 I get large character. Basically it pastes all values for D and A together, so D1_vs_A1_vs_D1_vs_A2_vs_D1_vs_A3 etc. Is does this for both group1 and group 2 and they seem to be identical at first sight. As a result res1 and res2 return NA as result